# Convert a column of lists into a column of vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.table` that for some reason has a few columns as `list`. I need to find a fast way to convert these columns to regular vector columns with `integer` values.

See reproducible example and my attempt below.

#### reprex

```
dt = structure(list(fromId = c("89a901291abffff", "89a901295b7ffff", 
      "89a9012809bffff", "89a901285cfffff"), travel_time_p001 = c(45L, 
      43L, 38L, 27L), travel_time_p050 = list(54L, 52L, 44L, 35L), 
      travel_time_p098 = list(62L, 60L, 55L, 44L)), row.names = c(NA, 
      -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


head(dt)
>             fromId travel_time_p001 travel_time_p050 travel_time_p098
> 1: 89a901291abffff               45               54               62
> 2: 89a901295b7ffff               43               52               60
> 3: 89a9012809bffff               38               44               55
> 4: 89a901285cfffff               27               35               44

sapply(dt, class)
>     fromId travel_time_p001 travel_time_p050 travel_time_p098 
>"character"        "integer"           "list"           "list" 

class(dt$travel_time_p098[1])
> [1] "list"
```

I've found this way to fix a single column, though I'm not sure this could be done faster.

`dt[, travel_time_p098 := Reduce(rbind, travel_time_p098)]`

Now, the challenge gets harder when I try to do this for multiple columns. This is what I've tried without success. I hope someone could come up with a fast solution, perhaps using a `data.table` loop with `set()`.

```
# identify which columns need to be transformed.
colpositions <- sapply(dt, class) == 'list'
colnms <- names(dt)[colpositions]

# failed attempt
dt[, colnms := Reduce(rbind, .SD), .SDcols = colnms]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `list` elements are of the same length as the number of rows, an option is to loop over all the columns, do a check with `if/else` and `unlist`

```
dt1 <- dt[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.list(x)) unlist(x) else x)]
str(dt1)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ fromId          : chr  "89a901291abffff" "89a901295b7ffff" "89a9012809bffff" "89a901285cfffff"
# $ travel_time_p001: int  45 43 38 27
# $ travel_time_p050: int  54 52 44 35
# $ travel_time_p098: int  62 60 55 44
```

---

Or without any checks

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, unlist)]
```

---

If we need to use `set`

```
for(j1 in seq_along(dt)) {
     cl1 <- class(dt[[j1]])
     if(cl1 == 'list') {
          set(dt, i = NULL, j = j1, value = unlist(dt[[j1]]))
        }
  }
   

str(dt)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ fromId          : chr  "89a901291abffff" "89a901295b7ffff" "89a9012809bffff" "89a901285cfffff"
# $ travel_time_p001: int  45 43 38 27
# $ travel_time_p050: int  54 52 44 35
# $ travel_time_p098: int  62 60 55 44
```

Comment: This solution using a loop with `set` works brilliantly. Thanks